# jQuery: Link disappears when parent animates

Tags: jquery

I have a DOM like this:

```
<div id="book-container">
    <div id="book-inner">
       Contents of slidedown
    </div>
    <a href="#" id="book-tab">Slide Down</a>
</div>
```

and I have this jQuery

```
$('#book-tab').on('click', function(){
   $('#book-container, #book-inner').animate({
      'height' : 350
   })
})
```

It works fine, but the problem is while `#book-container` and `#book-inner` is animating the `#book-tab` link disappears and reappears when it's finished animating.

Can anyone explain why it's doing this and how to fix it. It's not a huge problem, but I'd much prefer it if it didn't happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#book-tab').on('click', function(e){
    $('#book-inner').animate({
      'height' : 350
   })
})​
```

Use animation just for the inner div.

Working [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ghokun/WNeq7/3/)

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#book-tab').on('click', function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $('#book-container').animate({ // apply animation only one element
      'height' : 350
   })
})
```

Comment: I can't, they're both set to `height: 0` so they both need to animate